# cgridview modal link passing data

Tags: yii, modal-dialog, cgridview

How do I pass data for that row?

In cgridview:

```
array(
    'header'=>'Message',
    'type'=>'raw',
    'value' => 'CHtml::link(substr($data->comments, 0, 70)."...","#",array("data-toggle"=>"modal","data-target"=>"#message","data-id" => "$data->comments"))',)
```

under TbModal

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){   
                        var comments = $this.data('id');
                        $("#message").val(comments);
                }
            );
            </script>
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

replace `"data-id" => "$data->comments"` with `"data-id" => \'$data->comments\'`